# UICollection View Stationary Background View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using UICollectionView and am trying to build in a background image. This may be a simple solution/question.

I've read up on supplementary views and decoration views but wondered whether it was possible to add a subview to the collection view which doesn't move, pan or zoom when the collection view does?

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView has a property backgroundView, which you can use to show some background image.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you set a view below your collectionview with same frame and set your collectionview with transparent background?